# Teach ASP.NET MVC to treat key-less query values as boolean flags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

If a query value in URL doesn't have a key, e.g.: `http://site.com?update`
and an action has bool argument named update.
I want that update argument to received value `true` if 'update' value is present in the URL, and `false` otherwise.

Example:

Action: `public ActionResult MyAction(string name, bool update) {...}`
URL: `http://site.com/path?name=Bob&update`
Expected action call: `controller.MyAction("Bob", true);`

if URL is `http://site.com/path?name=Bob` (notice no **update**)
then expected call is `controller.MyAction("Bob", false);`

It is not a big deal, I **do** know I can just get `Request.Query` and find values with key=null, but I want to have it done through the framework.

Where do I begin?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this through the framework would probably require you to implement your own value provider with a corresponding value provider factory and add the factory to ValueProviderFactories. You would probably implement it similar to the existing QueryStringValueProviderFactory and QueryStringValueProvider but then add your own implementation of GetValue that includes the additional logic you wanted to return true/false based on if there is a value provided for the query string key. Here is a link on adding a value provider, and check out the QueryStringValueProvider in the framework.

http://mgolchin.net/posts/19/dive-deep-into-mvc-ivalueprovider